# Load multiple files into webpack without insane usage of using import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm making a webpack project, and inside this webpack project i have a bunch of 'mod' files, which need to be loaded.

I have one main Module file, which all of them extend and every file has a method which when called executes the mod.

Now there's like 20 of those files or so, and I dont want to be using `import` 20 times in my main.ts file, so are there any better and efficient ways of loading files?

Answer (score 1):

Main files usually are just a pile of imports, as it is where your application comes together. You could try and write a loop like,

```
const packages = ['package-a', 'package-b', etc...];
packages.forEach((pkg) => import { thing: `${pkg}-exec` } from `${pkg}`)
```

But it's pretty nasty syntax that could cause some annoying issues. I would do a more thorough examination of the tradeoffs before just dropping those lines into your project.

Comment: Thanks for the command, thats what I thought about too. Even tho this is not what I would like to do, it seems like this is the only option that I have.